# DT SWISS 1800C Spline converting from 142-12mm to 135-10mm thru bolt

Tags: wheels, hub, conversion

I'm building up my AWOL 2016 model and bought new wheels and front fork. With the front wheel I have no issue, but the back wheel presents a small problem.

The wheels i bought are DT Swiss C 1800 SPLINE db 23 - Wheelset - Clincher - Centerlock / IS - FW: 12/15x100mm / QR | RW: 12x142mm / QR - 2019

I want to convert them to 135x10mm through bolt and not through-axle, as my frame doesn't support it. I emailed DT Swiss and they advised me to buy this conversion kit:

> Caps: DT Swiss Conversion Kit for 240s/350 RW Disc Brake to 10x135mm Thru Bolt - HWGXXX0006560S
>
> Thru bolt: DT SWISS Quickrelease RW RWS Thru Bolt TA10 135x10 mm

All looked good until I got them. The main issue is that they do not have those, steel ribs (Have no clue how to call them properly) and just look like a standard thru axle end caps.

They look more like this version, but in 10mm:

> DT Swiss Conversion Kit for 180/240s/350 RW Disc Brake to 12x135mm Thru Axle - HWGXXX0003910S

There is another version of those end caps, like this one: HWGXXX00S3218S, but apparently they won't be compatible with my hub.

It seems that even retailers have a hard time to give a proper advice.

In short, they should have some sort of a lock nut on them, but they don't. When I was writing this, I came across the conversion kits from Mavic from 135 to QR and they also don't have those steel ribs on the sides. Is it normal those days and can I just install those end caps with RWS and it will be fine and secure?

Comment: Sounds like the same recommendation as on their [website](https://www.dtswiss.com/en/support/conversion-charts/end-cap-solution-road-rear/) but are you confident you received the correct item? Some online retailers’ images show the steel ribs for the product matching the code you ordered. Doesn’t mean they’ve used the right images, but makes me want to check you received the right thing

Comment: Indeed! That's why i was confident! However one retailer said that this is an old image and it's not from the actual product. I've looked around and indeed it seems that this is a  standard image of the different end caps.

Comment: Would you take a photo of the product you received and ask DT Swiss again? It seems you already contacted them. If you receive an answer it would be fantastic if you posted it as an answer here.

Comment: I did mailed them and few more shops, but didn't received anything on Friday. Hope to get some info today. Will post it here. It seems that there are a lot of different adapters from 15 and 12 mm thru axles to QR without that serration. I've checked Mavic site and their adapters don't have that serration either.

Comment: Hello guys. I've contacted DT Swiss, Retailer and another company (Reverse) who also produces thru bolts for standard 12mm thru axle wheels without serration and explained the situation. 

The response was pretty much the same from all three sides. 

It's totally fine for adapter not to have serration on the inside, as with thru bolt the wheel is keept in place by the bolt itself which is firmly secured in place by the outside serration and greater force. 

In short, all three said that it will be just fine and i should not worry about it.

Comment: In all honesty, I've checked and most of those adapters from 15 and 12 mm to 10 mm and quick release don't have that serration on the inside. 

I can assume that if there was a real safety issue, we would have heard about it by now. Instead overwhelming majority of buyers is actually praises those adapters in their reviews.

So i will just go with it and install it.

Comment: That sounds like it is all in order then, good stuff. If you’ve followed, and double checked the manufacturer’s instructions, that’s the best way